# Simple Calendar display Java program. Having issue with display pattern condition in for loop

Tags: java

**Problem:**

Write a JAVA program that produces a calendar. Your program should output a calendar for a single month, given parameters to specify how many days in the month and the day of the first Sunday.

I have written this program and need help in fixing the loop condition

**Expected results**
[image]

**Actual Result:**
[image]

My code has running | spaces and is unable to add floating spaces with pipes when the calendar has no value in the day field. I believe the issue is with this loop, I am hardcoding 35 which needs to be replaced with some condition that allows to print padded pipes.

```
for (int j = days; j < 35; j++) {
    System.out.print("|");
    System.out.printf("%6s", " ");
}
```

**My code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calendart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of days in the month: ");
        int days = console.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of the day of the first Sunday: ");
        int sunday = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        calendarHeader();
        borderTopBottom();
        calendarBody(sunday, days);
        borderTopBottom();
    }

    static double getInt(Scanner sc, String s) {
        int d = 0;
        System.out.print(s);
        d = sc.nextInt();

        return d;
    }

    static void calendarBody(int sunday, int days) {
        int temp = 8 - sunday;
        if (sunday == 1) {
            System.out.printf(""); // if sunday is on 1st day, then do not print any spaces
        } else
            for (int space = 1; space <= temp; space++) { // Prints spaces to the first row if no days are listed
                System.out.print("|");
                System.out.printf("%6s", " ");
            }

        for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++) { // Printing the days
            temp++;
            if (temp % 7 == 0)
                System.out.println("|" + padded(i, 4) + " " + "|");
            else
                System.out.print("|" + padded(i, 4) + " ");

        }

        for (int j = days; j < 35; j++) {
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.printf("%6s", " ");
        }

        sunday = (sunday + days) % 7;
    }

    static void calendarHeader() {
        System.out.print(" Sun ");
        System.out.print("Mon ");
        System.out.print("Tue ");
        System.out.print("Wed ");
        System.out.print("Thu ");
        System.out.print("Fri ");
        System.out.print("Sat");
    }

    static void borderTopBottom() {
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            System.out.print("+");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("+");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static String padded(int n, int width) {
        String s = "" + n;
        for (int i = s.length(); i < width; i++) {
            s = " " + s;
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code, also what exactly do you need help with in the for loop. I ran your code, and it appears to run fine, just the formatting is messed up.
Also I fail to see the point of this   for (int j = days; j < 35; j++) , I take this is meant to fill up the blank space?

Comment: yes, code runs find and i am able to get it to work but If you refer to screenshot for expected and actual result. My actual has rundown on pipes/spaces. I think it is because of I am hardcoding 35 in this for loop condition : for (int j = days; j<35; j++) I want to avoid the hardcoding and still be able to print the leftover empty days in the calendar... failing to come up wiith how to have the end condition.

Comment: I posted an answer that I think solves your main issue. If it helps you out don't forget to accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your biggest problem (apart from the formatting issues). The problem is that you're hardcoding the value that prints blank spaces. U can simply use the remainder of the number of days divided by 7.

```
int remainingDays = days % 7;

for (int j = 0; j < remainingDays; j++) {
    System.out.print("|");
    System.out.printf("%6s", " ");
}
if(remainingDays > 0)
    System.out.println("|");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am really new to programming, mostly fixing issues by trying. This does help some.. but problem is remaining days are not always days%7. Last row outcome will vary with what day will be first sunday. So still have spaces not populated. Last row space formatting is what I cannot get right.